# Getting elements from xml and storing it in array using shell script

Tags: xml, bash, xpath, sed, xmllint

I have my xml like :

```
<URLS xmlns:"http://www.example.com">
    <Service>
        <forwardUrl>
            <value>http://www.example1.com:80</value>
            <value>http://www.example2.com:80</value>
            .
            .
            .
       </forwardUrl>
    </Service>
</URLS>
```

I want to store all the forward urls in an array.

I tried doing this :

```
let urlcount=$(sed -e "s/xmlns/ignore/" /tmp/in.xml | xmllint --xpath "count(//forwardUrl/value)"  -)
declare -a urls=()

for((i=1; i <= $urlcount; i++)); do
    echo $i
    urls[$i]=$(sed -e "s/xmlns/ignore/" /tmp/in.xml | xmllint --xpath '//forwardUrl/value["$i"]/text()' -)
done
```

But when I do `echo ${urls[7]}`, it prints all the values.

I want to store different urls in different indexes. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this using only `sed`:

```
$ cat file1
<URLS xmlns:"http://www.example.com">
    <Service>
        <forwardUrl>
            <value>http://www.example1.com:80</value>
            <value>http://www.example2.com:80</value>
            <value>http://www.example3.com:80</value>
            <value>http://www.example4.com:80</value>
       </forwardUrl>
    </Service>
</URLS>
$ declare -a array=($(sed -n '/\s*<forwardUrl>/,/<\/forwardUrl>/p' file1 | sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g' -e '/^\s*$/d' -e 's/\s*//g'))
$ echo "${array[0]}"
http://www.example1.com:80
$ echo "${array[1]}"
http://www.example2.com:80
$ echo "${array[2]}"
http://www.example3.com:80
$ echo "${array[3]}"
http://www.example4.com:80
$ echo "${array[@]}"
http://www.example1.com:80 http://www.example2.com:80 http://www.example3.com:80 http://www.example4.com:80
$
```

Expression breakdown:

```
declare -a array=($(sed -n '/\s*<forwardUrl>/,/<\/forwardUrl>/p' file1 | sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g' -e '/^\s*$/d' -e 's/\s*//g'))
```

1. `sed -n '/\s*<forwardUrl>/,/<\/forwardUrl>/p' file1` to print lines in between lines that match `<forwardUrl>` and at `</forwardUrl>`(both inclusive)
2. `sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g' -e '/^\s*$/d' -e 's/\s*//g'` 1st expression deletes all tags, 2nd deletes all empty lines(having spaces) and last expression just removes all spaces

Edit 1:

```
$ cat file1
<URLS xmlns:"http://www.example.com">
    <Service>
        <forwardUrl>
            <value>http://www.sun.com:80</value>
            <value>http://www.example2.com:80</value>
            <value>http://www.example3.com:80</value>
            <value>http://www.example4.com:80</value>
       </forwardUrl>
    </Service>
</URLS>
$ declare -a array=($(sed -n '/\s*<forwardUrl>/,/<\/forwardUrl>/p' file1 | sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g' -e '/^\s*$/d' -e 's/\s*//g'))
$ echo "${array[0]}"
http://www.sun.com:80
$ echo "${array[@]}"
http://www.sun.com:80 http://www.example2.com:80 http://www.example3.com:80 http://www.example4.com:80
$
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but with this expression, even all 's' are getting removed. For example in www.sun.com, it is showing www.un.com. sed -e 's/\s*//g'  : This is not needed, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$ urls=($(sed -nr 's_<value>(.*)</value>_\1_p' file)); echo ${urls[1]}
http://www.example2.com:80
$ echo ${urls[0]}
http://www.example1.com:80
```

obviously doesn't care about the xml structure so assumes "value" tag is used only for urls.

**UPDATE:** if the context is important `awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F'[<>]' -v RS="</?forwardUrl>" 'NR==2{for(i=3;i<=NF;i+=4) print $i}' file

http://www.example1.com:80
http://www.example2.com:80
```

the rest is the same

```
$ urls=($(awk ... ))
```

note that this regex RS is gawk specific and may not be supported in other awks.

Comment: No there are other value tags as well which are inside some other tag. But I am interested only in value tags inside forwardUrl tag.

Comment: wrt `It doesn't work for me` - is that what you tell your mechanic when you drop off your car at the garage or do you give them any additional info that might give them a clue how to `make it work for you`? You will get out of this question whatever you put into it and `It doesn't work for me` is one of the worst responses you could give.

Comment: I am sorry. I didn't mean it that way.  I just wanted to inform him that the awk script he has written doesn't work for me and I don't have knowledge of awk that much.

Comment: @PriyanshGoel your awk may not support regex RS.  It's in gawk.